Does ground effect affect a paraglider/ canopy?
I've heard that ground effect is only significant if the wing is closer to the ground than its span, and I've never seen a canopy/ paraglider that would qualify for that.
Is that true or would there be some significant effect? (Based on theory or at least data.)
Let's assume that there is no bank/ roll (which is a separate question).
My thinking is that even if the ground effect does not reach the wing but somehow affects the pilot's body or the lines, it might just be enough to be significant.
This is because parafoils are lighter, softer, and with greater CL-CG moment than most aircraft, so minor effects (such as drag bowing the lines, drag on the pilot, or the mass of the air being pulled along outside the wing) can significantly change the trim or performance.
